# Data is not matching y-axis domain

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I've a grouped bar chart using D3. Chart is built on using `d3.stack()` but somehow data is not matching with the y-axis domain and bars are having very small height. Can someone let me know what am I missing?

Snippet:

```js
//DATA
var data = [
  {
    category: "test1",
    type1: 100,
    type2: 200,
    type3: 0,
    column: "column1"
  },
  {
    category: "test1",
    type1: 0,
    type2: 0,
    type3: 500,
    column: "column2"
  },
  {
    category: "test2",
    type1: 150,
    type2: 100,
    type3: 0,
    column: "column1"
  },
  {
    category: "test2",
    type1: 0,
    type2: 0,
    type3: 400,
    column: "column2"
  }
];

//INITIAL SETUP
var margin = { top: 30, right: 10, bottom: 80, left: 80 };
var width = document.documentElement.offsetWidth - margin.left - margin.right;
var height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
var barwidth = 40;

var graph = d3
  .select("#chart-area")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var x0 = d3
  .scaleBand()
  .rangeRound([0, width])
  .paddingInner(0.1);

var x1 = d3.scaleBand().padding(0.05);

var y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]).domain([0,500]);

var y1 = d3.scaleBand();

var z = d3.scaleOrdinal().range(["#98abc5", "#8a89a6"]);
var stack = d3.stack().offset(d3.stackOffsetExpand);

x0.domain(
  data.map(function(d) {
    return d.category;
  })
);
x1
  .domain(
    data.map(function(d) {
      return d.column;
    })
  )
  .range([0, x0.bandwidth()])
  .padding(0.2);

z.domain(Object.keys(data[0]).filter(x => x !== "category" && x !== "column"));
var keys = z.domain(); //["type1", "type2", "type3"];

var stackData = stack.keys(keys)(data);

var serie = graph
  .selectAll(".serie")
  .data(stackData)
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  .attr("class", "serie")
  .attr("fill", function(d) {
    return z(d.key);
  });

serie
  .selectAll("rect")
  .data(function(d) {
    return d;
  })
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("class", "serie-rect")
  .attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "translate(" + x0(d.data.category) + ",0)";
  })
  .attr("x", function(d) {
    return x1(d.data.column)+x1.bandwidth()/ 2 - 20;
  })
  .attr("y", function(d) {
    return y(d[1]);
  })
  .attr("height", function(d) {
    return y(d[0]) - y(d[1]);
  })
  .attr("width", barwidth);

graph
  .append("g")
  .attr("class", "axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(d3.axisBottom(x0));

graph
  .append("g")
  .attr("class", "axis")
  .call(d3.axisLeft(y).ticks(null, "s"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="chart-area"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is just the use of `stack.offset(d3.stackOffsetExpand)`.

If you look at the API, you'll see that [`d3.stackOffsetExpand`](http://.offset(d3.stackOffsetExpand)):

> Applies a zero baseline and normalizes the values for each point such that the topline is always one.

Therefore, all your values go from `0` to `1`.

Here is the same code without the `d3.stackOffsetExpand`:

```js
//DATA
var data = [
  {
    category: "test1",
    type1: 100,
    type2: 200,
    type3: 0,
    column: "column1"
  },
  {
    category: "test1",
    type1: 0,
    type2: 0,
    type3: 500,
    column: "column2"
  },
  {
    category: "test2",
    type1: 150,
    type2: 100,
    type3: 0,
    column: "column1"
  },
  {
    category: "test2",
    type1: 0,
    type2: 0,
    type3: 400,
    column: "column2"
  }
];

//INITIAL SETUP
var margin = { top: 30, right: 10, bottom: 80, left: 80 };
var width = document.documentElement.offsetWidth - margin.left - margin.right;
var height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
var barwidth = 40;

var graph = d3
  .select("#chart-area")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var x0 = d3
  .scaleBand()
  .rangeRound([0, width])
  .paddingInner(0.1);

var x1 = d3.scaleBand().padding(0.05);

var y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]).domain([0,500]);

var y1 = d3.scaleBand();

var z = d3.scaleOrdinal().range(["#98abc5", "#8a89a6"]);
var stack = d3.stack();

x0.domain(
  data.map(function(d) {
    return d.category;
  })
);
x1
  .domain(
    data.map(function(d) {
      return d.column;
    })
  )
  .range([0, x0.bandwidth()])
  .padding(0.2);

z.domain(Object.keys(data[0]).filter(x => x !== "category" && x !== "column"));
var keys = z.domain(); //["type1", "type2", "type3"];

var stackData = stack.keys(keys)(data);

var serie = graph
  .selectAll(".serie")
  .data(stackData)
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  .attr("class", "serie")
  .attr("fill", function(d) {
    return z(d.key);
  });

serie
  .selectAll("rect")
  .data(function(d) {
    return d;
  })
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("class", "serie-rect")
  .attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "translate(" + x0(d.data.category) + ",0)";
  })
  .attr("x", function(d) {
    return x1(d.data.column)+x1.bandwidth()/ 2 - 20;
  })
  .attr("y", function(d) {
    return y(d[1]);
  })
  .attr("height", function(d) {
    return y(d[0]) - y(d[1]);
  })
  .attr("width", barwidth);

graph
  .append("g")
  .attr("class", "axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(d3.axisBottom(x0));

graph
  .append("g")
  .attr("class", "axis")
  .call(d3.axisLeft(y).ticks(null, "s"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="chart-area"></div>
```

On the other hand, if you do want to use `d3.stackOffsetExpand`, change the `y` domain accordingly:

```
var y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);
```

By removing the domain, it defaults to `[0, 1]`.

Here is the code with that change:

```js
//DATA
var data = [
  {
    category: "test1",
    type1: 100,
    type2: 200,
    type3: 0,
    column: "column1"
  },
  {
    category: "test1",
    type1: 0,
    type2: 0,
    type3: 500,
    column: "column2"
  },
  {
    category: "test2",
    type1: 150,
    type2: 100,
    type3: 0,
    column: "column1"
  },
  {
    category: "test2",
    type1: 0,
    type2: 0,
    type3: 400,
    column: "column2"
  }
];

//INITIAL SETUP
var margin = { top: 30, right: 10, bottom: 80, left: 80 };
var width = document.documentElement.offsetWidth - margin.left - margin.right;
var height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
var barwidth = 40;

var graph = d3
  .select("#chart-area")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var x0 = d3
  .scaleBand()
  .rangeRound([0, width])
  .paddingInner(0.1);

var x1 = d3.scaleBand().padding(0.05);

var y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);

var y1 = d3.scaleBand();

var z = d3.scaleOrdinal().range(["#98abc5", "#8a89a6"]);
var stack = d3.stack().offset(d3.stackOffsetExpand);

x0.domain(
  data.map(function(d) {
    return d.category;
  })
);
x1
  .domain(
    data.map(function(d) {
      return d.column;
    })
  )
  .range([0, x0.bandwidth()])
  .padding(0.2);

z.domain(Object.keys(data[0]).filter(x => x !== "category" && x !== "column"));
var keys = z.domain(); //["type1", "type2", "type3"];

var stackData = stack.keys(keys)(data);

var serie = graph
  .selectAll(".serie")
  .data(stackData)
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  .attr("class", "serie")
  .attr("fill", function(d) {
    return z(d.key);
  });

serie
  .selectAll("rect")
  .data(function(d) {
    return d;
  })
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("class", "serie-rect")
  .attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "translate(" + x0(d.data.category) + ",0)";
  })
  .attr("x", function(d) {
    return x1(d.data.column)+x1.bandwidth()/ 2 - 20;
  })
  .attr("y", function(d) {
    return y(d[1]);
  })
  .attr("height", function(d) {
    return y(d[0]) - y(d[1]);
  })
  .attr("width", barwidth);

graph
  .append("g")
  .attr("class", "axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(d3.axisBottom(x0));

graph
  .append("g")
  .attr("class", "axis")
  .call(d3.axisLeft(y).ticks(null, "s"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="chart-area"></div>
```

Comment: Thank goodness. I knew there was some silly mistake. This is what happens if I copy some code without knowing the whole details. Thanks!